# Wget on busybox v1.9.1

Tags: wget, busybox

I have busybox 1.9.1 runing in huawei router. There is few commands, one of them wget and I want to use it, but there is some strange syntax.

When I type wget www.google.com like I do normaly on my debian/mint etc, i get help message in this form:

```
Usage: wget [OPTION]... HOST

wget download and upload a file via HTTP

Options:
        -g    Download
        -s    Upload
        -v    Verbose
        -u    Username to be used
        -p    Password to be used
        -l    Local file path
        -r    Remote file path
        -P    Port to be used, optional
        -B    Bind local ip, optional
        -A    Remote resolved ip, optional
        -b    Transfer start position
        -e    Transfer length
        -m    Max transfer size
        -c    Compress downloaded file
```

I tried to use anything, like wget -g url or wget -g -r url, but nothing works, i always get only this help message again. Can someone help me?

Comment: Does it work if you specify the protocol? eg http:// ? And does it work if you try an IP-based url (eg wget http://127.0.0.1/).  And have you tried running su -before attempting the wget?

Comment: Hello, i tried both http:// and ip-based url, nothing worked. su is not working on this busybox ( not found )

Comment: Just thinking - the output of wget you've posted doesn't look like what BusyBox shows in their documentation - http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#wget. Is this another version of wget, or the one that comes with BusyBox?

Comment: Well, I get into this busybox throught huawei console via telneting my router and then using command "shell" in their console, so the busybox was probably specially crafted by huawei

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the other user was voted down. The correct syntax for my Huawei HG610 router is exactly as he says.

For example:

wget -g -v -l /tmp/test.html -r / 192.168.0.11

The above will retrieve the page at http://192.168.0.11/ and save it to /tmp/test.html

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same problem and finally got the correct syntax:

wget -g -v -l "path to save the file" -r "path to remote file" host (without http://)

hope it helps